# Why is SharePoint 2016 User Profile Service Importing unselected AD users?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile-service, active-directory-import

We are using AD Import with User Profile Service.  I am seeing multiple users from unselected containers appear in our Employee Directory.  These users have been deleted from Manage User Profiles but reappear.  These are active users but they shouldn't be in SharePoint.  I confirmed users do not appear in hidden list - MembershipGroupId=0.

Why are unselected users imported and how can I prevent them from being imported?

Comment: Are these users logging into SharePoint on any site in the farm?

Comment: Not that I can tell.